# Bounce/Vibration in a Beam drive by Harmonic Reducer

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, mechanisms, robotics

I have a system that is set up in the following way

- a harmonic reducer with a beam attached (50:1)
- the direction of rotation is perpendicular to gravity
- the beam extends to both ends at an equal distance with equal loads on either end.
- the beam is rigid
- the motion control is considered "smooth" relative to the observed bounce/vibration
- the motion control is an open loop with respect to the output of the reducer and will not respond to feedback/flex on the beam.
- the bounce will happen at constant velocities but with very low amplitude

When the beam is moving between two positions the beam begins to bounce or vibrate. Once the beam arrives at its position it will continue to bounce/vibrate at its natural frequency until the damping factor has reduced vibration to zero. This bounce occurs regardless of the direction of travel.

I currently believe the source of the bounce is the acceleration of the beam's moment of inertia which then puts a torsional force into the harmonic reducer, as the beam continues to accelerate the torsional energy is released back into the beam and pushes it with an additional force driving the beam fast than would be expected from the motor/drive system.

My question is:

- is there a simple way to go about modeling this? So I can understand the frequency of the vibration of the system relative to the applied acceleration and system mass.
- is my assumption about the primary source of vibration correct? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Please could you give some idea of beam dimensions materials masses and the signal of torque vs time during a typical maneuver. Then , yes, it is easy to model it as a single degree of freedom model (mass on cantilever), or worst case distributed mass in the cantilever plus mass at the end.

Comment: You might well find the rotational stiffness of the shaft motor and mountings contribute to the frequency of the resonance.